# Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction:

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to call a SOAP webservice using SAAJ for this WSDL. I submitted the request for this WSDL here `http://www.webservicex.net/ws/WSDetails.aspx?WSID=64`and it generated the following SOAP requests..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetGeoIP xmlns="http://www.webservicex.net/">
      <IPAddress>string</IPAddress>
    </GetGeoIP>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Using SAAJ I generated the same SOAP requests and submitted it but get this error - Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: .

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<GetGeoIP xmlns="http://www.webservicex.net/">
<IPAddress>SUNW</IPAddress>
</GetGeoIP>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Java Code:

```
package newpackage;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.soap.*;

public class SOAPClientSAAJ {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        // Create SOAP Connection
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

        // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
        String url = "http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx";
        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);

        // print SOAP Response
        System.out.print("Response SOAP Message:");
        soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);

        soapConnection.close();
    }

    private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

        String serverURI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";

        // SOAP Envelope
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsd", serverURI);

        SOAPBody body = soapMessage.getSOAPBody();
        QName bodyName = new QName("http://www.webservicex.net/", "GetGeoIP" );
        SOAPBodyElement bodyElement = body.addBodyElement(bodyName);
        QName name = new QName("IPAddress");
        SOAPElement symbol = bodyElement.addChildElement(name);
        symbol.addTextNode("SUNW");
        soapMessage.saveChanges();

        /* Print the request message */
        System.out.print("Request SOAP Message:");
        soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println();

        return soapMessage;
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like you need to set the soapAction header. Use the getMimeHeaders method on the soapMessage object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
    MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
    headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", "http://www.webservicex.net/" + "GetGeoIP");
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but I don't see any changes in the XML message...How does the Mimeheaders get added....<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body><GetGeoIP xmlns="http://www.webservicex.net/">
 <IPAddress>192.168.1.8</IPAddress>
 </GetGeoIP>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Comment: Good question.But i dont have a clear answer for this. As per my understanding, the message we print, has only the contents of SoapEnvelope. But SOAPAction is something above that at http msg level. did a little googling and found this(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP).

Comment: Also (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21455_01/common/tutorials/resolver_soap_action.html)

Comment: [http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl) provides some good examples on how the SOAPAction MIME header is embedded into a SOAP HTTP Request. It is quite a large document so I recommend searching the page for SOAPAction to find the relevant parts.

Comment: Calling the soapMessage.writeTo(System.out) BEFORE calling the message causes the "server did not recognizes.." error. Try without adding the mimeheder, but call the  soapMessage.writeTo(System.out) AFTER the line SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);. It will work.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Marshelling and Unmarsheling, Just implement `WebseviceMessageCallback` interface like:

```
public class SOAPConnector extends WebServiceGatewaySupport
{
    public Object callWebService( String url, Object request )
    {
        return getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive( url, request,  
webServiceMessage -> {
            (( SoapMessage )webServiceMessage).setSoapAction( 
"https://www.w3schools.com/xml/CelsiusToFahrenheit" );
        } );
    }
}
```

Otherwise proceed with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26253141/6097074

Comment: how do i add a header like content-type?

Comment: @MahmoudOdeh you can do like below:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62840806/6097074