# How to send a SOAP request using WebServiceTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, jaxb

I am trying to send a request to a SOAP webservice. I read [this tutorial](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html) and prepared the following code. However, I am going to send different requests to multiple SOAP webservices, whereas the tutorial focused on one request. How can I send SOAP request using `WebserviceTemplate`?

**WebServiceTemplate**

```
    SoapMessage soapMsg = new SoapMessage();
    soapMsg.setUsername("Requester");
    soapMsg.setPassword("Pass");
    soapMsg.setLanguageCode("EN");
    Request request = new Request();
    request.setDeparture("FDH");
    request.setDestination("HAM");
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat frm2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    request.setDepartureDate(frm2.parse(frm2.format(date)));
    request.setNumADT(1);
    request.setNumCHD(0);
    request.setNumInf(0);
    request.setCurrencyCode("EUR");
    request.setWaitForResult(true);
    request.setNearByDepartures(true);
    request.setNearByDestinations(true);
    request.setRronly(false);
    request.setMetaSearch(false);
    soapMsg.setRequest(request);
    WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate().  //how to create object and send request!
    Object response = webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(
            "https://aaa5.elsyarres.net", soapMsg);
    Response msg = (Response) response;
    System.err.println("size of results of wogolo:"
            + msg.getFlights().getFlight().size());
```

Comment: Do you have a good reason for doing this manually? You can generate a web service proxy if you have the services wdsl file. [Here](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcreate_client.html) are instructions for how to do this in eclipse.

Comment: @Pétur The issue is that I do not have wsdl, also I am going to send SOAP requests to multiple SOAP based webservices.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use following code, you do not need to define anything in xml file.

```
  try {
            SaajSoapMessageFactory messageFactory = new SaajSoapMessageFactory(
                    MessageFactory.newInstance());
            messageFactory.afterPropertiesSet();

            WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate(
                    messageFactory);
            Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();

            marshaller.setContextPath("PACKAGE");
            marshaller.afterPropertiesSet();

            webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(marshaller);
            webServiceTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();

            Response response = (Response) webServiceTemplate
                    .marshalSendAndReceive(
                            "address",
                            searchFlights);

            Response msg = (Response) response;
        } catch (Exception s) {
            s.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: if i don't set unmarshaller i get 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: No unmarshaller registered. Check configuration of WebServiceTemplate.' You can pass this exception with             'webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);'

Comment: What to put instead of PACKAGE?

Comment: @HerilMuratovic I'm using `setPackagesToScan` instead. Documentation says: `Set the packages to search for classes with JAXB2 annotations in the classpath. This is using a Spring-bases search and therefore analogous to Spring's component-scan feature`

Answer (score 8):

To send different SOAP requests to different SOAP services, you just need to make your WebServiceTemplate aware of all requests and responses it will have to process.

Create a Java class for each request and response like so:

```
package models;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.io.Serializable;

@XmlRootElement
public class FlyRequest implements Serializable {

    private boolean nearByDeparture;

    public FlyRequest() {}

    public boolean isNearByDeparture() {
        return nearByDeparture;
    }

    public void setNearByDeparture(boolean nearByDeparture) {
        this.nearByDeparture = nearByDeparture;
    }
}
```

(The @XmlRootElement is because we use JAXB marshaller below; see Jaxb reference for more info).

The setup of the template is done for example like so:

```
    SaajSoapMessageFactory messageFactory = new SaajSoapMessageFactory(MessageFactory.newInstance());
    messageFactory.afterPropertiesSet();

    WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate(messageFactory);
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setContextPath("models");
    marshaller.afterPropertiesSet();

    webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    webServiceTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
```

"models" is the name of the package where the Request/Responses classes are, so that jaxb can find them.

Then you just instantiate the request of the class you want to perform the call, like so:

```
    // call fly service:
    FlyRequest flyRequest = new FlyRequest();
    flyRequest.setNearByDeparture(false);
    Object flyResponse = webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive("https://example.net/fly", flyRequest);

    // call purchase service:
    PurchaseRequest purchaseRequest = new PurchaseRequest();
    purchaseRequest.setPrice(100);
    Object purchaseResponse = webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive("https://example.net/purchase", purchaseRequest);
```

Similarly, you can cast the response objects into your JAXB classes defined above.

Comment: I used the code but it returns following Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "my.project.flights.wegolo" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index

Answer (score 3):

Here is an Example what you should be looking for

Soap has a lot of restriction unlike `REST`, It follows some standards which have to be meet before you get Network call to work,

But unlike `Rest`, in Soap if you have `WSDL` URL you can get all the information needed to call the Soap call

```
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/";
private final String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
```

this code was written in `Android` so you can ignore some part of it but I still kept it in answer so someone from android background can put a good use to it

Open `[WSDL][1]` in browser and check for the things which matter to call a remote method on server.

> 1
>   you will see an attribute `targetNamespace` whose value would be `Namespace` which you will use in this case `Namespace` is `http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/`
>
> 2
>   Now you require the name of the method this `WSDL` has four method each of the are int attribute `s:element` with the value is the name of the Method in this case four methods are  `FahrenheitToCelsius`, `FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse`, `CelsiusToFahrenheit`, `CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse`
>
> 3 
>   Now you have to fure out the `SOAP Action` which is `NAMESPACE+METHOD`
>   but WSDL also gives information about that as well, look for the tag `soap:operation` and it's  `soapAction` attribute havs the Soap action as it's value in this case which we want to call is `http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit`

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            SoapObject soapObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            soapObject.addProperty("Celsius","12");


            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);
            HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            httpTransportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive soapPrimitive = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            Log.d("TAG", "doInBackground: "+soapPrimitive.toString());

            return soapObject.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        textView.setText(""+aVoid);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems it is not using WebServiceTemplate of Spring framework am I right? I am interested in learning about SOAP support of Spring framework

Comment: are you using soap:soap:2.3.1 library to make the soap call

Comment: @Jack, if possible, Kindly provide WSDL url, I will update the answer so that you can check

Comment: The problem is, I do not have WSDL.

Comment: URL is now: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?wsdl

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your SoapMessage is marhsallable

To send the same message to multiple endpoints you only need to loop on the sending code and the request handler.

Something like this:

```
{
    String endpoint = "https://aaa5.elsyarres.net"
    WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate().
    webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri(endpoint);
    Object response = webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(soapMsg);
    // handle you are response as you are currently doing.
    // Loop changing the endpoint as you need.
}
```

This code uses the Spring WebServiceTemplate

Answer (score -1):

I tried many options and finally below one worked for me if you have to send soap header with authentication(Provided authentication object created by wsimport) and also need to set soapaction.

```
public Response callWebService(String url, Object request)

{
    Response res = null;
    log.info("The request object is " + request.toString());

    try {
        
        

        res = (Response) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(url, request,new WebServiceMessageCallback() {
                 @Override
                  public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) {
                    try {
                      // get the header from the SOAP message
                      SoapHeader soapHeader = ((SoapMessage) message).getSoapHeader();

                      // create the header element
                      ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
                      Authentication auth =
                          factory.createAuthentication();
                      auth.setUser("****");
                      auth.setPassword("******");
                     ((SoapMessage) message).setSoapAction(
                                "soapAction");

                      JAXBElement<Authentication> headers =
                          factory.createAuthentication(auth);

                      // create a marshaller
                      JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Authentication.class);
                      Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();

                      // marshal the headers into the specified result
                      marshaller.marshal(headers, soapHeader.getResult());
                      
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                      log.error("error during marshalling of the SOAP headers", e);
                    }
                  }
                });

        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return res;

}
```