# Android Ksoap2 web services asmx

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-studio, android-ksoap2

`getresponse()` or `androidHttpTransport.call` doesn't work. No error caused still yields no response. `ksoap` version 3.3.0 . help please.

```
  `private static String NAMESPACE="http://www.ogrencibitpazari.com/webservis";

 `private static String URL= "http://www.ogrencibitpazari.com/Webservice.asmx?WSDL";

 `private static String SOAP_ACTION="http://www.ogrencibitpazari.com/webservis/urunler";

`private static String METHOD_NAME="urunler";    

`public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab1);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewBooks);
    OzelAdapter adaptorumuz=new OzelAdapter(this, kisiler);
    listView.setAdapter(adaptorumuz);
     txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    getir();
}



 private final void getir()
{
    `new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;


            try {

                **androidHttpTransport.call**(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

                for (int i = 0; i < response.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
                    deg = response.getPropertyCount();
                    Object property = response.getProperty(i);
                    SoapObject info = (SoapObject) property;

                    String id = info.getProperty("urun_id").toString();
                    String yol = info.getProperty("yolu").toString();
                    String fiyat = info.getProperty("urun_fiyat").toString();

                    txt.setText("" + yol);
                    kisiler.add(new urunler(0, "" + yol, 0));

                }
                String ad = " ";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34368029/how-to-send-a-soap-request-using-webservicetemplate/34368514#34368514

Comment: I try but doesnt work please help