# How to insert in database from android with a webservice soap

Tags: android, web-services, soap

i'm trying to insert an object "Personne" with nom,prenom and mail into database from android with soap .in my logcat there are no errors .it's a 202 status request failed in my phone.

this is the message in my logcat:

[image]

below is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.projet.ma/create";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "create";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.projet.ma/";
    private static final String URL = "http://ip@:8080/WebService/NewWebService?WSDL";




    EditText nom;
    EditText prenom;
    EditText mail;
    Button b;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        nom=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView);
         prenom=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
         mail=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
         b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == b) {
            try {
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new
                            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                }
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
//PropertyInfo PI = new PropertyInfo();
                Toast.makeText(this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(nom.getText().toString() != "" && prenom.getText().toString() !="" &&
                        mail.getText().toString() !="") {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "bien", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    request.addProperty("create",
                            new Personne (nom.getText().toString(), prenom.getText().toString(),
                                    mail.getText().toString() ));
                    Toast.makeText(this, "bien", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new
                        SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
// envelope.dotNet = false;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: you can check this example, i learned from here you can learn everything about how to upate, insert,delete, add.   http://www.thaicreate.com/mobile/android-json-from-url.html

Comment: you should be making a network call off the Main thread.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34368029/how-to-send-a-soap-request-using-webservicetemplate/34368514#34368514