# I am getiing issue in SOAP V1 Magento in Android

Tags: php, android, magento

I'm trying to use soap v1 in order to create an cart product in magento webservice . I'm able to perform basic operations with the SOAP v1 Api but I got stuck on a method .

https://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.add.html

public static final String URL_SESSION = "xyz/index.php/api/soap";

```
 public static final String METHOD_NAME_ADDCART ="cart_product.add";
 public static final String SOAP_ACTION_ADDCART ="urn:Magento/cart_product.add";
```

public static final String NAMESPACE_SESSION = "urn:Magento";

issue is :
SoapFault - faultcode: 'SOAP-ENV:Server' faultstring: 'Procedure 'cart_product.add
' not present' faultactor: 'null' detail: null

api user having full permission in the back end and it is working in IOS. but in an Android still it is not working. please some one help me to find the solution.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34368029/how-to-send-a-soap-request-using-webservicetemplate/34368514#34368514

Comment: Pankaj thank for reply . i have reviewd that link but got failed because i need to implement magneto Soap V1.