# Android Client server issue

Tags: android, web-services, jakarta-ee, ksoap2

Below I have given the details of the server code running on tomcat server it generates the wsdl file correctly.

In my android emulator I have *KSOAP2* Lib file installed to access the web service.

Please help me resolve the issue.
Whenever I add two numbers in the device it should the call the server code.

I have error log attached

**Function on the server:**

```
[
package com.testing;

public class Calculator {

    public int addidtion(int a, int b ){

        return a*b;
    }

}

]
```

**Code:**

```
[
 b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                int SDK_INT = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                if (SDK_INT > 8) {
                    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                            .permitAll().build();
                    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);

                    String i = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText)).getText().toString();
                    String J = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4)).getText().toString();

                    //Use this to add parameters

                    request.addProperty("addidtion", i);
                    request.addProperty("addidtion", J);


                    //Declare the version of the SOAP request

                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);


                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                    envelope.dotNet = false;

                    try {

                        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);


                        //this is the actual part that will call the webservice

                        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);


                        // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.

                        SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;


                        if (result != null)

                        {

                            //Get the first property and change the label text
                            EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
                            text.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());

                        } else

                        {

                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                }

            }
        });


]
```

**WSDL:**

```
[
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://testing.com"><!--WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.4
Built on Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT)
--><wsdl:types><schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://testing.com"><element name="addidtion"><complexType><sequence><element name="a" type="xsd:int"/><element name="b" type="xsd:int"/></sequence></complexType></element><element name="addidtionResponse"><complexType><sequence><element name="addidtionReturn" type="xsd:int"/></sequence></complexType></element></schema></wsdl:types><wsdl:message name="addidtionResponse"><wsdl:part element="impl:addidtionResponse" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="addidtionRequest"><wsdl:part element="impl:addidtion" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part></wsdl:message><wsdl:portType name="Calculator"><wsdl:operation name="addidtion"><wsdl:input message="impl:addidtionRequest" name="addidtionRequest">

       </wsdl:input><wsdl:output message="impl:addidtionResponse" name="addidtionResponse">

       </wsdl:output></wsdl:operation></wsdl:portType><wsdl:binding name="CalculatorSoapBinding" type="impl:Calculator"><wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/><wsdl:operation name="addidtion"><wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/><wsdl:input name="addidtionRequest"><wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input><wsdl:output name="addidtionResponse"><wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output></wsdl:operation></wsdl:binding><wsdl:service name="CalculatorService"><wsdl:port binding="impl:CalculatorSoapBinding" name="Calculator"><wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8011/testws/services/Calculator"/></wsdl:port></wsdl:service></wsdl:definitions>

]
```

**Error:**

```
03-23 10:00:11.490 6275-6275/com.example.suvidhs.activity W/System.err: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.SoapFault cannot be cast to org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
03-23 10:00:11.490 6275-6275/com.example.suvidhs.activity W/System.err:     at com.example.suvidhs.activity.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:98)
03-23 10:00:11.490 6275-6275/com.example.suvidhs.activity W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
03-23 10:00:11.491 6275-6275/com.example.suvidhs.activity W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
03-23 10:00:11.491 6275-6275/com.example.suvidhs.activity W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
03-23 10:00:11.491 6275-6275/com.example.suvidhs.activity W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-23 10:00:11.491 6275-6275/com.example.suvidhs.activity W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
03-23 10:00:11.491 6275-6275/com.example.suvidhs.activity W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
03-23 10:00:11.491 6275-6275/com.example.suvidhs.activity W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-23 10:00:11.491 6275-6275/com.example.suvidhs.activity W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
03-23 10:00:11.491 6275-6275/com.example.suvidhs.activity W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Your error log clearly says that your have imported wrong _SoapObject_

Comment: here is an example that you can check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34368029/how-to-send-a-soap-request-using-webservicetemplate/34368514#34368514

Comment: Hi, Piyush and Pankaj can any one of you give me your skpe ID.